# using HashMaps is it possible to return all keys that have values below a set threshold?

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

Is it possible for return all values of a `HashMap` if they're below a certain value? This is the Hash:

```
Map<String, Integer> StockIO = new HashMap<>();
```

The `String` being the stock item and `Integer` being the stock value.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here.

This is the correct working and tested code using a jbutton click that then prints to a textarea:

```
private void OrderActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    Set<String> keys = new HashSet<>();
    for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry: StockIO.entrySet()) 
    {
        if (entry.getValue() <= 10) 
        {
            keys.add(entry.getKey());
            Oresult.setText(entry.getKey());
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add an example of a Threshold?

Comment: @PeterRader by threshold I mean, if value equals less than 10, return all stock that meets that criteria

Comment: Iterate the `entrySet()`?

Comment: sorry @Kayaman could you give me an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get your question fully, but check this code below. May be it is what you want:

```
HashMap<String,Integer> jj=new HashMap<String, Integer>();
jj.put("A",10);
jj.put("B",20);
jj.put("c",30);
jj.put("Bd",50);
jj.put("Af",40);
jj.put("Bd",240);
jj.put("Ads",130);
jj.put("Bde",240);
jj.put("As",130);
jj.put("Bfe",210);
int threshold=100;
for(String key:jj.keySet()){
    String stock_item=key;
    Integer stock_value=jj.get(key);
    if(stock_value<threshold)
        System.out.println("Item:"+stock_item+" "+" Value:"+stock_value+"\n");
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it isn't efficient. If you want ordering, use an ordered map, i.e. a `TreeMap`.

Comment: I had looked at TreeMaps, but order isn't important, I really would just want it to tell me all the items that met the criteria, no particular order, just the fact that their stock level is below a number

Comment: Make up your mind. If order isn't important why are you looking for all key values below a threshhold?

Comment: because it'll be used to order the new stock items if the levels drop below a certain level, the only criteria that's important is if the value of the hashmap is less than a number

Comment: @EJP Sc001010tt wants the stocks (= keys?) for whose the value is below a criteria. It's a filtering on values, not on keys. So `TreeMap` is unfortunately useless here.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is effectively filtering your collection of keys.

With this code, you get all the keys that have a value lower than or equal to a specific threshold.

```
public static Set<String> keysWithValuesBelowThreshold(Map<String,Integer> map, int threshold) {
  Set<String> keys = new HashSet<>();
  for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry: map.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue() <= threshold) {
      keys.add(entry.getKey());
    }
  }
  return keys;
}
```

With Java 8:

```
public static Set<String> keysWithValuesBelowThreshold(Map<String,Integer> map, int threshold) {
  return map.entrySet().stream()
      .filter(e -> e.getValue() <= threshold)
      .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
      .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Comment: @Sc001010tt I know it's your right, but I don't understand. So would you please tell me what my answer is missing, that compelled you to remove the accepted answer mark? You ask to "return", so that implies a separate function (which I did); you ask to return "keys" (which I did again); you ask to filter values "below a set threshold" (which also did). What is my answer missing, that made you uncheck my answer? The method is reusable. Remember that if an answer is useful, you can give it +1 by clicking the up arrow next to the answer. Especially since your edit in the question uses my answer.

Comment: oh sorry @Oliver i thought I could tick 2 answers, I'm not use to using this site as much i'd like to be, It was a honest mistake, I couldn't flaw your answer but the laid with in my asking

Comment: Well, technically, the up arrow gives +1, meaning that an answer is good and the check mark means that an answer is the best one. the up arrow can be applied to any number of answer, the check mark can be applied to only one.